# Master Detail - reparenting options

Tags: apex, custom-object, master-detail

I have a custom object Candy__c. Candy__c has an Account__c field that is a master detail to Account. I am cloning an account record and want to KEEP the old account record. Yes there will be duplicates in the system, we are okay with this. We want to reparent the Candy__c record to the new Account record.

I read that re-parenting master detail relationships are not possible within Salesforce.  Would my only option be to clone the Candy__c record and associate to the new Account record?

Comment: It is possible, but dependent on the configuration of the M-D field.

Comment: Specifically, there is an option (when you create/edit a Master-Detail relationship field) to allow re-parenting. It is not enabled by default.

Comment: thank you @AdrianLarson I forgot we can update this setting on the object.